# How to route to sub directories from, when there is no trailing slash?

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4

I am using react-router v4

Let's assume I am at the following location

```
http://localhost:3000/articles
```

I want this location to have a react router Link element, which points to

```
http://localhost:3000/articles/new
```

**first try:**

```
 <Link to="new" />
```

points at

```
http://localhost:3000/new
```

**second try:**

```
 <Link to="/new" />
```

from any location points at

```
http://localhost:3000/new
```

**third try:**

```
 <Link to="new" />
```

from

```
http://localhost:3000/articles/ /* notice the slash at the end */
```

points at

```
http://localhost:3000/articles/new
```

**success, but I need it to work from:**

```
http://localhost:3000/articles
```

Comment: Can you post your Routes file?

Comment: sorry but the routes are spread among several files, so that would be too much code

Answer (score 0):

You should point the `Link` to `/articles/new`

`<Link to="/articles/new" />`

You Router should be similar to this:

```
const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <div className="wrapper">
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
      <Route path="/articles" component={Articles} />
      <Route path="/articles/new" component={New} />
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

*Note:* Configuring your Router as the example will render both components (Articles and New). If you want to reder only the New, you should add the property `exact` to the parent component.

`<Route path="/articles" exact component={Articles} />`

Comment: the problem with this solution is when I have something like "userID/articles/new"  I need to manage the userID and create the route then. So I was hoping there is a simpler way of doing this...

Comment: For that you can use parameter directly on your route using `:`.

so the `userID/articles/new` should be something like `:userID/articles/new` 

You can find more information about it on: [react-router-tutorial](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/06-params)

Comment: I ended up with something like this, I take the whole path and set the route each time the user changes. But it seems like this is not the most elegant way...